# Starmap modifying a parameter before passing it in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a strange bug that I'm encountering when trying to use multiprocessing.Pool.starmap. The minimum code needed to reproduce the bug is here :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Ignore the fact that this class is useless as-is, it has more code but it wasn't relevant to the bug
class Coordinate(tuple) :                                                                          

    def __new__(cls, *args):                                                                   
        return tuple.__new__(cls, args)                                                        

#Essentially just stores two coordinates
class Move :                                                     

    def __init__(self, oldPos, newPos) :      
        self.oldPos = oldPos                  
        self.newPos = newPos                  

    def __str__(self) :      
        return 'Old pos : ' + str(self.oldPos) + ' -- New pos : ' + str(self.newPos)

#Dummy function to show the problem
def funcThatNeedsTwoParams(move, otherParam) :
    print(move)             
    # Second param ignored, no problem there

p = Pool(2)  
moveOne = Move(Coordinate(0, 2), Coordinate(0, 1))
moveTwo = Move(Coordinate(2, 1), Coordinate(3, 0))
moveThree = Move(Coordinate(22345, -12400), Coordinate(153, 2357))
# The numbers are irrelevant, no effect on whether problem shows up or not

moves = [moveOne, moveTwo, moveThree]
paramsForStarmap = [[move, 'other param'] for move in moves]

print(paramsForStarmap)
#Output : 
#[[<__main__.Move object at 0x1023d4438>, 'other param'], [<__main__.Move object at 0x1023d4470>, 'other param'], [<__main__.Move object at 0x1023d44a8>
for move in [params[0] for params in paramsForStarmap] :
    print(move)
#Output : 
#Old pos : (0, 2) -- New pos : (0, 1)
#Old pos : (2, 1) -- New pos : (3, 0)
#Old pos : (22345, -12400) -- New pos : (153, 2357)
p.starmap(funcThatNeedsTwoParams, paramsForStarmap)
#Output :
#Old pos : ((0, 2),) -- New pos : ((0, 1),)
#Old pos : ((22345, -12400),) -- New pos : ((153, 2357),)
#Old pos : ((2, 1),) -- New pos : ((3, 0),)
```

Basically, I have an array of pairs of parameters, something like this : [[move, otherParam], [move, otherParam], ...], I print out every first parameter to show that the moves are valid before using the starmap function. Then I call the starmap function using the pool that was created earlier, and tell it to use the pairs of parameters I have. Then, inexplicably, every move's coordinates become tuples of the form ((coordinate), ), instead of (coordinate).

I can't seem to figure out why starmap would change the properties of an object passed to it, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting one. The issue isn't just with `starmap`. It happens with all `Pool` functions - `apply`, `map`, etc. And, as it turns out, the issue isn't with `multiprocessing` at all. It's happens when you pickle/unpickle the `Coordinate` class:

```
>>> c = Coordinate(0,2)
>>> print(c)
(0, 2)
>>> str(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(c)))
'((0, 2),)'
```

Pickling a `tuple` subclass isn't as straightforward as it looks, at it turns out. You can fix it by defining a [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) method that fixes the pickling process:

```
class Coordinate(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, args)

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self.__class__, tuple(self))
```

Now it pickles just fine:

```
>>> c = Coordinate(0,2)
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(c))
(0, 2)
```

And your example code works fine, too.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! How did you find out that pickling was what was causing the issue?

Comment: @MarcusBuffett Well, first I noticed that the breakage happened when I used `map` and `apply`, so I knew it wasn't a `starmap` problem. Then I added print statements inside of the `Pool` code to trace the output of printing the `Move` instance, and noticed that the point at which the `Coordinates` got broken was as soon as it got to the worker process. My next thought was that something weird was happening when `Coordinate` got pickled, since it was a `tuple` subclass, which an unusual pattern. So I tested it and confirmed that was the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Last question, you said you added print statements inside the Pool code, how did you do that? Seems like a useful debugging trick

Comment: @MarcusBuffett Opened up /usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py in a text editor, and started hacking away. :)

Comment: @dano: do you have any idea why the Coordinates do not pickle correctly/intuitively?  Is this potentially an outright bug in Python?  It seems pickling a tuple works fine, so why not a derived class?

Comment: @JohnZwinck it's a good question, and when I get some time I'm planning on digging into the `pickle` code to try to root cause it. It certainly *seems* like a bug on the surface.